# Why does React freezes when Re-fetching data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, fetch

I have problem about performance, it works fine on first fetch, sometimes on second and third fetch also, but on fourth fetch it freezes until I close the page. I have no idea what's going on. its always like this no matter how big data will be

### This is performance test

[image]

### This is fetch function

```html
async fetchData(start, end) {
    try {
      // debugger;
      const URL = "exampleUrl";

      var myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append("Authorization", "exampleToken");

      let formdata = new FormData();
      formdata.append("act", "report1");
      formdata.append(
        "data",
        `{"start_date": "${start}", "end_date": "${end}"}`
      );

var requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: formdata,
  redirect: "follow",
};
 const response = await fetch(URL, requestOptions)
 const json = await response.json()
 this.setState({data: json.data})
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(start)
  }
```

first time i call this **function on componentDidMount**

```html
  componentDidMount() {    
      this.currentDate();
      this.addRow()
      this.fetchData(this.state.startDate, this.state.endDate);
      this.fetchUniqueData(this.state.startDate, this.state.endDate);
      this.handleRow();
      setTimeout(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            this.fillCheckboxes(i);
        }
      }, 500);
      
  }
```

And on **ComponentDidUpdate I reFetch** it every time date changes

```html
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevStats){
   if(this.state.startDate !== prevStats.startDate){
     this.updateStartDate(this.state.startDate)
     this.updateEndDate(this.state.endDate)
     this.fetchData(this.state.startDate, this.state.endDate);
     this.fetchUniqueData(this.state.startDate, this.state.endDate)
   }
  }
   //update start date state on date change
  updateStartDate = (start) => {
    this.setState({startDate: start})        
  }
  //update end date state on date change
  updateEndDate = (end) => {
    this.setState({endDate: end})
  }
```

It makes a little bit good when Im using **shouldComponentUpdate**

```html
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.startDate !== nextState.startDate;
  }
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Could you create a minimal reproducible issue?

Comment: sorry, didn't got what you asked you want me to do example?

Comment: Yes, a small runnable software with only the code needed to reproduce that error so that others can try to help you :-)

Comment: @PrateekThapa i cant make it in sandbox couse my api blocking it cant fatch from there but the issue is like first time its fetching very fast second time a little bit later but fast anyway and on third time it always needs 18seconds on fourth its dead

Comment: You could use a mock function that returns the same value instead of calling the API though.

Comment: @PrateekThapa yes but i can't use date changer on that, and my app is freezing when i'm changing the date